# Enums and static typing

Tags: gdscript

I have declared an enum in some gdscript code.

Then, I want to declare some variables to be of that type of enum.

Is this possible. I know GDScript allows to declare a static type of a var. MEvery language I have used allows you to treat an enum as a var.

The following code produces the following error for me...

```
enum XDir {
    None,
    Left,
    Right
}

enum YDir {
    None,
    Up,
    Down
}

var x_dir : XDir
var y_dir : YDir
```

> Parser Error: Identifier 'XDir' is not a valid type (not a script or
>   class), or could not be found on base 'self'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible yet. Enums in GDScript are syntactic sugar for constant dictionaries and are not actual types.

You'll have to use `int` as the type until enums are made into real types.

Do note that you can still give enums to `export` like

```
export(XDir) var x_dir: int
```

To enforce an enum value at runtime you can do:

```
assert(XDir.has(x_dir))
```